# How do I get the next-to-last register for a select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, sqlplus

### Environment

Virtual machine with OracleXE11g (I'm using `SQL Plus`)

### Explanation

I need to get with 1 query (and without `pl/SQL`):

- The last `SQL` statement that was executed in the server
- The number of times that statement was executed since It was first loaded in the Shared Pool
- The CPU time it took of executing for that same statement

All in all, this is the query that I figured out

```
SELECT sq.SQL_TEXT ,sq.EXECUTIONS, sq.CPU_TIME
  FROM gv$sql sq;
```

Of course, this query is working, but it shows all the registers. I need to get the next-to-last one, because the last one would be that same query when It got executed.

### What I'm trying to achieve

How could I get the next-to-last register of that query?

Comment: Not super familiar with 11g, but isn't there a date field you could use with a window function?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Or a real problem?  I struggle to imagine how this information would be useful to you since the SQL statement you find will almost certainly be from a background process Oracle is running in the background.

Comment: It will FIRST require an ORDER BY, then research into the FETCH NEXT... with OFFSET clauses

Comment: You are right, this is a homework assignment, so there's no need of having a real use in a real environment. We are just learning about users, privileges, roles...etc @JustinCave

Comment: I tried the fetch statement but is not working with 11g version. I found that it was first introduced with 12c release @DRapp

Comment: Well, It's true that I found something related to timestamps to probably solve this problem. I found this piece of code ```select * from t where TIMESTAMP_COLUMN = ( select max(timestamp_column) from T )
and rownum = 1;``` but never tried it, because I can't understand it well @tim

Answer (score 0):

Use [`row_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) with descending order, take second row:

```
select sql_text, executions, cpu_time 
  from (select sql_text, executions, cpu_time, 
               row_number() over (order by last_load_time desc) rn
          from gv$sql)
  where rn = 2;
```